# How to properly handle custom helper methods in a 'shared' folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, module, view-helpers

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to *organize* and *share* custom helper-view methods as-like I made for my view files. That is, in my `app/views` directory I have a `shared` folder where I put all shared templates and I would like to have a `shared` folder (intended to be used the same "sharing way" but for helper files) also in the `app/helpers` directory.

However, my doubts are:

1. Is right to share helper methods instead of putting those in the `ApplicationHelper` module (even if those helper methods are specific for *shared* views and not directly related to any model or controller)?
2. How can I load modules present in the `app/shared/helpers` directory in order to make those available to views?
3. Is there some prescriptions to this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails, helpers are actually global. Which means that you can call a user helper in a, say, posts view. So you don't really have to pollute ApplicationHelper, just divide them in the best way possible, and just use them normally.

Comment: Do you mean that if I create the `app/helpers/shared` directory and I put in it helper files then all related helper methods will be available in views?

Comment: Yeah. Whatever modules you place in helpers will actually be visible throughout the **all** the views.

Comment: And what about "doubts" **1** and **3**?

Comment: For point 1, it's actually a Rails design issue. Point 3 would be related to what I answered: Place related methods into their helpers, and that's almost as far as it gets. There's a growing alternative approach to helpers, which is the use presenters instead.

Comment: @BenjaminTanWeiHao I have a custom helper which is inside the auth folder(but not in the helpers folder), How can I make use of these helpers on the view page?